# Unity3d + Facebook SDK - Switching Scenes

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

Before trying to do anything stupid I wanted to ask the experts: what are the best practices on the scenario of switching scenes?

Does Unity3D retain the information of `FB.Login()` on the first scene forever, or do I need to initialize `FB` on every scene I loaded?

Sorry to ask before testing it, I am away from my dev machine and really curious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some research and found out that if we create a static class, with a static property it will remain the same as long as the game runs.

So I created 1 static class with a static property of my FacebookUser class and it remained active while switching scenes.